# Overloading ‘in’ operator to do comparison upon subcomponent of the sequence’s elements while preserving other properties

Tags: python, operator-overloading

While I was trying to solve the following issue, I found an interesting example to understand even better the new operator and ways of using it.

The problem:
If we have any sequence (list, tuple, set) L of tuples (or sequences in general), and we want that a comparison like (e in L ) be based on one component of elements from the sequence, such like : 
1 in { (1, 'b') } == True
The first idea could be to define a simple class which keeps the sequence object and the component index, then defines its operator ‘in’:

```
SubComp_Seq :
    def __init__(self, Seq, CompIndex) :
        self.Seq = Seq
        self.CompIndex = CompIndex

    def __contains__(self, Elem) :
        for SeqElem in self.Seq :
            if Elem == SeqElem[self.CompIndex] :
                return True
        return False
```

mySet = SubComp_Seq ({ (1, 'b'), 0 }

1 in mySet => True

Though that this definition will work perfectly, but the object made from the class SubComp_Seq will not have any of the properties of the original sequence (like .add ).

Yet, I found a better way to write a class preserving the properties of the original object. Before exposing my solution, I starve to see variety of Pythonists solutions. Especially if there is one solution for which the sequence’s add primitive will use our defined ‘**contains**‘.

Answer (score 0):

One gotcha would be by overloading the equality operator. So I tried the following solution:

```
class CompEqSeq :
    def __new__(cls, Obj, *ArgLst, **ArgKw) :

        class CompEqSeqMeta(type(Obj)) :
            def __new__(Cls, Obj, *ArgLst, **ArgKw) :
                inst = super(CompEqSeqMeta, Cls).__new__(Cls, Obj)
                return inst

            def __hash__(self) :
                h =  super(CompEqSeqMeta, self).__hash__()
                print("hash", h)
                return h

            def __init__(self, Seq, CompIndex) :
                super(CompEqSeqMeta, self).__init__()
                self.CompIndex = CompIndex

            def __eq__(self, Other) :
                Comp = self.CompIndex
                if isinstance(Other, type(Obj)) :
                    return self[Comp] == Other[Comp]

                return Other == self[Comp]

            return CompEqSeqMeta(Obj, *ArgLst, **ArgKw)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    a, b = CompEqSeq((1, 'a'), 0), CompEqSeq((2, 'b'), 0)
    Seq1 = {a, b}
    z = (2 , 'z')
    print("z == b", z == b)
    Seq1.add(z)
    print("Seq1",Seq1)
    print("z in Seq1", z in Seq1)
    print("2 in Seq1", 2 in Seq1)
```

We can see how elements are enrobed by a class which preserves all their properties as it is derived from their real class type(Obj).
Un fortunately, the last line of the code will give False, as the operator ‘in’ did not use our defined ‘__eq__’ against elements of 'Seq'.
As I do not know how ‘in’ operator does work exactly!

Whatever, the usage of the __new__ operator here is quite intersting.